# Prove that $T(\vec u) = T(\vec v)$ if and only if $T(\vec u - \vec v) = \vec 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear transformation.  Prove that $T(\vec u) = T(\vec v)$ if and only if $T(\vec u - \vec v) = \vec 0$
I do not know how to begin this proof, can someone help me?

Comment: Have you looked up what it means that $T$ is linear? If you look at the definition of that, do you see something that might help with this?

Comment: What is \v, MathJax doesn't recognize it? Is it just a function called v?

Comment: Begin by writing the definition of "linear".  If you do nothing, the question is likely to be closed.

Comment: I guess `\v{u}` should be `\vec{u}` to yield $\vec{u}$.

Comment: So I know the definitions to be linear are 
$TA(\bar{u} + \bar{v}) = TA(\bar{u}) + TA(\bar{v})$
and
$TA(c\bar{u}) = cTA(\bar{u})$
But I don't know how to incorporate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We say that the transformation $T:V\to W$ is *linear* if $T(v + w) = T(v) + T(w)$ whenever $v\in V$ and $w\in V$ and $T(\alpha v) = \alpha T(v)$, where $\alpha\in\textbf{F}$, $v\in V$ and $\textbf{F}$ is the underlying field where the vector spaces $V$ and $W$ are defined. Based on such definition, you get what is required:
\begin{align*}
T(u) = T(v) & \Longleftrightarrow T(u) - T(v) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow T(u) + T(-v) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow T(u + (-v)) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow T(u - v) = 0
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!